# Angular nested controller error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to nest controller and I am getting the following error: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined. I searched and I sow that there is a similar question but the answer was not applicable to my case.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<body ng-controller="MainController" layout="column">
<div>
    <md-content flex >
        <div>
            <md-toolbar class="md-accent">
                <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                </div>
            </md-toolbar>
        </div>
        <md-content flex layout-align="center center">
            <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" layout="column" id="sideNav">
                <section layout="column">
                    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin/Index", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "myButtons" })
                    </md-button>
                </section>
            </md-sidenav>
            <md-button  class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="clickSide('left')">Show menu</md-button>
            <md-content class="AppContainer">
                @RenderBody()
            </md-content>
        </md-content>
        <footer>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                <h2>My Awesome Footer  &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</h2>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </md-content>
</div>
</body>
```

app.js(main controller)

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute']);

MyApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope,$rootScope, $http,  $filter, $mdDialog, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $window, $location) {
$scope.clickSide = function (dir) {
    $mdSidenav(dir).toggle();
};

});
```

AdminController.js

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $mdDialog) {
$scope.test = "Hello";

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to declare the Module again in the AdminController, Change it as follows,

```
MyApp.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $mdDialog) {
$scope.test = "Hello";    
});
```